# Is it possible to remove one Production Certificate permanently?

Tags: ios, xcode6, ios-provisioning

I have noticed that I have 2 Production certificates in the Apple developer account, the only difference is:
 - one expires Jun 24 2016
 - the other one expires Jul 27 2016

I don't know how this happened but it is causing so many troubles, as it seems that I don't have the private key for one of them and I get errors every time I try to archive some apps.

Is it possible to delete one of them? (If I revoke it, will it be deleted from there?)

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revoke certificate will be deleted from list!